# Is it required for a website/file-sharing site to log the IP of downloads?

Tags: internet, website, security

MediaFire claims they keep no logs of who downloads or accesses your folders. Is this legal and if it's not true, could they get into any legal trouble from it?

[image]

[image]

- The first image is there support answering my question on whether they keep logs of downloads, etc
- The second image is there data retention policy
- Finally, the company is based in Texas, I'm not familiar with the local laws there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the US, it is legal not to log (the NSA will do it anyway).

One possible reason that logging *could* be made required by law is to assist in tracking copyright violators. But I am not aware of any US regulators proactively enforcing such logging policy on file sharing service providers (such regulators do exist in some other countries though).

However, a claim by a file sharing service provider that it does not log, that is not on its website but just made in response to a query sounds like blatant BS. The logging of HTTP requests (which include the IP and web browser name/version) is normally done by default out of the box; the service provider would need to put efforts to turn this logging off. Although they could genuinely do this to make their service more attractive (think of VPN providers having logging turned off), this would indirectly position them as friendly to copyright infringement, which could make them a liable party should serious violation occur (Megaupload was a good example). Therefore, there are good reasons to:

1. Tell some curious prospective customers that there is no logging;
2. Keep logging.

Comment: My question is do they log IP addresses so that they know who saw this or downloaded that. They claim to delete logs after 3 hours and then after 72 hours its deleted from there memory cache. Also, the site is https and logging who saw the site with google analytics is a no brainer. However, do they connect their logs of IP addresses to exact https links or files someone views?

Comment: they also claim to use 3rd party analytics such as google analytics

Comment: @NRSJ The question of what they actually do is off-topic here, let alone not answerable by anyone but them. Noone here can/would tell you if they are actually telling the truth.

Comment: ok then, then what do you mean by the NSA would anyway, do they log every website in the universe or something SMH. Also thank you for the answer

Comment: AND it wasn't just a query response,it was on there website also. https://www.mediafire.com/policies/data_retention.php

Comment: @NRSJ The NSA comment is just a bit of a sarcasm pointing out that if MediaFire doesn't log you it doesn't mean you are not logged. Regarding what NSA actually does you can google "edward snowden nsa". Again, noone on this site would tell with 100% certainty what they (can) log.

Comment: @NRSJ: Google analytics can only tell you that a user viewed a download landing page, not whether they followed through with the download offered on that page.